# ng-repeat $index for a form field array (ie add new option)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two select fields using `ng-repeat` method I was adding (clone) the inputs.

I was two different array to maintain to push and remove the object. 
But I need to maintain in single array is possible?

My working fiddle is here [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hn3taeeo/24/)

Comment: where is the fiddle?

Comment: please provide working fiddle

Comment: @Sajeetharan  
pls check my updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/hn3taeeo/24

Comment: @RiddhiGohil Please check my fiddle now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes possible, just have  `$scope.model.campuses = [];`only, and have a object for school and campus and push it to the array

```
  function newCampus() {
        $log.log("Adding a new campus");
        $scope.model.campuses.push({Campus :$scope.model.campus, School :$scope.model.school});

    }
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/vLen161k/4/)

Comment: it is only adding first select values . I want to add both select field values into single Array

Comment: sorry i deleted by mistake check this one http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/vLen161k/4/

Comment: Thanks I will try and let u know

Comment: but first set values stored in outside of array

Comment: bro its just the model, rmeove the model from the expression if you do not want to see http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/vLen161k/6/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124493/discussion-between-ben10-and-sajeetharan).